# calling a class method of reading csv file into servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am wrting a code to send email from mulitple sender to one recepient in a continuous loop. I have to read senders emailID  from csv file for that I have written a code for raeding as follows:

```
public class ReadFile {

    CsvReader senders;

    public CsvReader read(){

        try {
            senders = new CsvReader("C:/Users/D/Documents/Senderlist.csv"); 
            senders.readHeaders();

            while (senders.readRecord())
            {
                String SenderID = senders.get("SenderID");
                String ReceiverID = senders.get("ReceiverID");

                // perform program logic here
                System.out.println(SenderID + " : " + ReceiverID);
            }

            senders.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("senders");
        //traversing list through iterator 
        Iterator itr=al.iterator();  

        while(itr.hasNext()){  
            System.out.println(itr.next());  
        }  
        return senders;

    }

}
```

Now how do I call this method in my servlet to read and send emails in continuous loop, servlet is as follows:

```
public class MailController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String ExchangeIP;
    private String port;

    public MailController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void init() {
        // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        ExchangeIP = context.getInitParameter("ExchangeIP");
        port = context.getInitParameter("port");
    }

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // read from field
        List<File> uploadedFiles= saveUploadedFiles(request);
        String sender=request.getParameter("sender");// reading from the form page
        String recipient=request.getParameter("recipient");
        String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
        String content=request.getParameter("content");
        String resultMessage = ""; 

        try {
            EmailUtility.sendEmail(ExchangeIP, port,user, recipient, subject, content, uploadedFiles);
        resultMessage = "The e-mail has been sent successfully";
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
        } finally {
            //deleteUploadFiles(uploadedFiles);
            request.setAttribute("Message", resultMessage);
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }   

}
```

Comment: are you uploading something like the csv file to servlet ? or just trying to invoke the message sending process in the servlet ? whats your `saveUploadedFiles(request);` is doing here ?

Comment: that is for uploading attachment ..I have not shown the code for attachment in servlet here..i have sender Email Ids store in csv file now i want to use that senderlist for sending emails one by one in loop to single recipient. So i have written this Readfile class to read csv file as shown above and the prblm I am facing is how to call that read method in servlet class & how to apply loop to send the emails..(I am begineer to  java development.)

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is to read the CSV file and iterate the items you read from that file in `Servlet` then why dont you simply call the `read()` method in the servlet ? And change the `read()` method like this

```
public List<String> getSenderEmails() {
        CsvReader senders = new CsvReader("C:/Users/D/Documents/Senderlist.csv");
        senders.readHeaders();

        List<String> senderEmails = new ArrayList<>();

        while (senders.readRecord()) {
            String senderID = senders.get("SenderID");
            String receiverID = senders.get("ReceiverID");

            // perform program logic here
            System.out.println(senderID + " : " + receiverID);
            senderEmails.add(senderID);
        }

        return senderEmails;
}
```

**NB:**

- I dont know whats your `CsvReader` is doing. But assuming here it is kind of a library or Util calss. So necessary `Exception` handeling is required.
- But the main idea I am suggesting is instead of returning `CsvReader` or something like that just return the list of email address you are just concern about.

Next thing is you can call the `getSenderEmails()` from servlet and iterate over it to send emails

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // read from field
    List<File> uploadedFiles = saveUploadedFiles(request);
    String sender = request.getParameter("sender");// reading from the form page
    String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");
    String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
    String content = request.getParameter("content");
    String resultMessage = "";    

    try {
        List<String> senderEmails = ReadFile.getSenderEmails();
        for (String user : senderEmails) {
            EmailUtility.sendEmail(ExchangeIP, port, user, recipient, subject, content, uploadedFiles);
        }
        resultMessage = "The e-mail has been sent successfully";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly Where should I call this method (getSenderEmail() ) in servlet class above..

Comment: updated the answer. But its not clear from your question that what exactly you are trying to do after sending email successfully. so I omitted redirection logic. But this should send emails when the servlet is fired.

Comment: I just want to send bulk email one by one from different senders to only one recipient through this code.

Comment: I have tried it. its giving me null pointer exception..how to iterate senders("user" in sendEmail method) so that to send bulk emails

Comment: I just gave u the basic idea and I guess you meant `user` as the email address you got from the csv. u need to look around for error handling as I have no idea about your other source codes. NB: updated the code. variable name in forearch loop is edited. u can try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have class name, ReadFile

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static ReadFile thisCls;
    private String filename = "C:/Users/D/Documents/Senderlist.csv";

    public static ReadFile getSenderClass()
    {
        if(thisCls == null) thisCls = new ReadFile();

        return thisCls;
    }

    private CSVRead() {}

    public List<String []> readCsv() {

        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename));
            // UTF-8
            // CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8"), ",", '"', 1);
            String[] s;
            while ((s = reader.readNext()) != null) 
            {
                data.add(s);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Then, Your servlet class might be

```
public class MailController extends HttpServlet {

    .....skip code....


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // read from field
        List<File> uploadedFiles= saveUploadedFiles(request);
        String sender=request.getParameter("sender");// reading from the form page
        String recipient=request.getParameter("recipient");
        String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
        String content=request.getParameter("content");
        //String resultMessage = ""; 
        List<String> resultMessage = new ArrayList<String>();

        //<==============================
        CSVRead read = new CSVRead();
        List<String[]> data = CSVRead.readCsv();

        //assuming you have a sender in a second column value
        Iterator<String[]> it = data.iterator();

        String targetSender = null;

        try {
            String[] array = (String[]) it.next();

            targetSender = array[1];

            EmailUtility.sendEmail(ExchangeIP, port,sender, recipient, subject, content, uploadedFiles);

            resultMessage.add("The e-mail has been sent successfully to " + targetSender);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            resultMessage.add("There were an error: " + ex.getMessage() + " while sending user " + targetSender);
        }


        try{
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    String[] array = (String[]) it.next();

                    targetSender = array[1];

                    EmailUtility.sendEmail(ExchangeIP, port,targetSender, recipient, subject, content, uploadedFiles);

                    resultMessage.add("The e-mail has been sent successfully to " + targetSender);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    resultMessage.add("There were an error: " + ex.getMessage() + " while sending user " + targetSender);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            //deleteUploadFiles(uploadedFiles);
            request.setAttribute("Message", resultMessage);
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } 

    }

}
```

I don't know about the sendEmail method of EmailUtility class.
I assume that the 3rd parameter must be a sender.